# What is the Oracle SQL query to select data by date time range

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT *
FROM (table name)
WHERE project_name = '(Project name' 
  AND tool_name = 'x'
  AND result_type = 'Warning'
  AND UTC_END_TIME >= TO_DATE('2021-04-06 05:01:52', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
  AND UTC_END_TIME <= TO_DATE('2021-04-08 05:15:44', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

I tried this query to retrieve data form the this specific date range not able to find out the exact output, but I'm getting the output for the **2021-02-30 05:00:31** mentioned date.

Comment: Query looks OK, syntax is OK, so - what does it mean that you aren't able to find exact output? What *is* exact output? Though, as you used >= and <=, you could have used BETWEEN instead of that, but that's irrelevant in this case, wouldn't solve anything.

Comment: Ha! Right, as EllisCoding said (in deleted answer), 30th of February is invalid so ... how are you getting output for such a date?

Comment: Please edit your question to show some sample data, the actual output you are currently getting (you haven't fixed the 2021-02-30 value in the output), what you expected to get instead (for that sample data), and explain why what you are seeing is wrong. The column data type would be helpful too. Basically a [mre].

Comment: What is this `(table name)`  ? Do you really use special cast from PL/SQL variable to a table?

Comment: What is the data type of UTC_END_TIME column?

Comment: Yes its UTC_END format

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue, you can try using the BETWEEN operator to specify the date range in the SQL query.

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE project_name = '(Project name' 
  AND tool_name = 'x'
  AND result_type = 'Warning'
  AND UTC_END_TIME BETWEEN TO_DATE('2021-04-06 05:01:52', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
                       AND TO_DATE('2021-04-08 05:15:44', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

Here, the BETWEEN operator is used to select records that fall between the two specified dates. The TO_DATE() function is used to convert the date strings to the DATE data type, which is required for the BETWEEN operator to work correctly.

Comment: `BETWEEN` is effectively the same as the `>=` and `<=` operators used in the question. Why/how does this fix the issue - not that we really know what the issue is, as it hasn't been explained yet...?

Answer (score 0):

What is the data type of UTC_END_TIME? Does it include time zone? In which case, you might be subject to timezone conversion depending on the timezone of your client. Try running explain plan on your query:

```
explain plan for
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE project_name = '(Project name' 
  AND tool_name = 'x'
  AND result_type = 'Warning'
  AND UTC_END_TIME BETWEEN TO_DATE('2021-04-06 05:01:52', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
                       AND TO_DATE('2021-04-08 05:15:44', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

Then run

```
select * from table( dbms_xplan.display )
```

and look at the predicate information for a clue